# Mapping the world with selected colored countries

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, coordinates, ggmap

I am trying to map the world highlighting only determined countries based on my data.
What I am trying to achieve is to color in shades of blue the negative values (the bigger the number, the darker the color, e.g. -5 would be dark blue, -1 light blue) and in shades of red the positive (5= dark, 1 = light red).
Also, I wanted to give labels accordingly ("-5","-4","-3"..."4","5"); I am only interested in cutting the values in 11 clusters (from -5 to +5) meaning a country with value 97 would be colored the same as a country with value 5.
Here's my code:

```
library(RColorBrewer)
library(maptools)
library(ggplot2)
if (!require(gpclib)) install.packages("gpclib", type="source")
gpclibPermit()

data(wrld_simpl)

ddf = read.table(text="
                 country value
                 'Argentina' 2
                 'Australia' 3
                 'Belgium' 5
                 'Brazil' 17
                 'Canada' 2
                 'China' -2
                 'France' 7
                 'Germany' 97
                 'Indonesia' -2
                 'Italy' 9
                 'Japan' 9
                 'Portugal' -2
                 'Russia' 3
                 'Saudi Arabia' 2
                 'Singapore' -5
                 'Slovenia' 1
                 'Spain' -3
                 'Switzerland' 0
                 'Turkey' 0
                 'United States' 18", header=TRUE)

plotme <- function() {
  
  # align colors to countries
  
  ddf$brk <- cut(ddf$value, 
                 breaks= -5:5,
                 include.lowest=TRUE)
  
  # this lets us use the contry name vs 3-letter ISO
  wrld_simpl@data$id <- wrld_simpl@data$NAME
  
  wrld <- fortify(wrld_simpl, region="id")
  wrld <- subset(wrld, id != "Antarctica") # we don't rly need Antarctica
  
  gg <- ggplot()
  
  # setup base map
  gg <- gg + geom_map(data=wrld, map=wrld, aes(map_id=id, x=long, y=lat), fill="white", color="#7f7f7f", size=0.25)
  
  # add our colored regions
  gg <- gg + geom_map(data=ddf, map=wrld, aes(map_id=country, fill=brk),  color="#7f7f7f", size=0.25)
  
  # this sets the scale and, hence, the legend
  gg <- gg + scale_fill_manual(values=colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(11,'RdBu'))(length(ddf$value)), 
                               name="Country")
  
  # this gives us proper coords. mercator proj is default
  gg <- gg + coord_map()
  gg <- gg + labs(x="", y="")
  gg <- gg + theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent", colour = NA),
                   panel.border = element_blank(),
                   panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent", colour = NA),
                   panel.grid = element_blank(),
                   axis.text = element_blank(),
                   axis.ticks = element_blank(),
                   legend.position = "bottom")
  gg

}

plotme()
```

I don't understand why it doesn't use the palette I chose (it should have blue too), and also I cannot make the  "labels = " argument work in the cut() function. Some countries (France, Germany, USA) do not get colored also!
Here's the plot I get:

[image]

THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!

Comment: Does replacing `length(ddf$value)` in the scale with `nlevels(ddf$brk)` help at all?

Comment: unfortunately, no.. but thanks for the effort!